# Save Dialog box in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, savefiledialog

i am working on Silverlight 5,

Application has functionality like save data in user's local pc as CSV. while developing functionality it's working perfect at our local PC. when we click on "Export" Button save file dialog box appear and save at selected location. but after deployed on our server save file dialog box will not appear on screen.

```
dialog = new SaveFileDialog();

dialog.DefaultFileName = "Exported Data";
dialog.Filter = string.Format("File Type (*{0}) | *{0}", (".csv"));
dialog.DefaultExt = string.Format("{0}", ("csv"));

//Show the dialog              
bool? dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call ShowDialog() method right after "Export" button click event, this is Silverlight security feature.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog(v=vs.95).aspx

> You show a save dialog control using the ShowDialog method. For security purposes Silverlight file and print dialogs must be user-initiated. This means you must show them from a user-initiated action such as the click event handler for a button. In addition, there is a limit on the time allowed between when the user initiates the dialog and when the dialog is shown. If the time limit between these actions is exceeded, an exception will occur.